# xcode 4.3.2 prompted me to change debuggers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have been prompted by xcode 4.3.2 to update my debuggers as it was giving me warning. I think it was somthing along the lines of GCC and LLMV or something.. anyway I changed and now I cannot build my apps onto the iphone 5.1 simulator.

I am woundering how to get it so that I can get my simulator working again.. it actually makes xcode hang.. what do I do?

Comment: You haven't asked a question...

Comment: lol sorry.. just frustrated not thinking straight. I have updated my question.

Comment: Does it show any errors?  Little red exclamation marks etc...

Comment: Also try closing down the simulator and xcode completely and opening them again.  Apple's developer tools have issues...

Comment: No warnings or errors. What happens is that it says its compiled and you wait for ages then as soon as you say bring the doc up or try to view the simulator you get the rainbow loading thing over then it hangs.. if i open up force quit it has the not responding error next to the name xcode.

Comment: I have restarted the computer trying to get it sorted.. and its still doing the same thing.

Comment: Well without any error messages etc, it's a little tough for people to help... Maybe try reverting back to the previous compiler/debugger.  Other than that I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Im not sure how to revert? what should I set it too?

Comment: So I have just tried changing the compiler settings and I think thats what has been changed.. I am using the default apple LLVM is that correct?

Comment: The project I'm working on at the moment uses the LLVM GCC 4.2, but I can't see why using the default would be a problem.

Comment: Its giving me a ton of "Expected a property attributeefore'strong'"